# Graceful way of stopping at the end of an enumerator?

Tags: ruby, loops, enumerators

Is there a graceful way of realizing one is at the end of an enumerator?

For instance,

```
a = (1..10).to_a
e = a.each
e.next # should yield 1
while e.next
  # do something
end
```

Of course, e raises [StopIteration](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/StopIteration.html)
when you get to the end of the enumerator.

Is there a nice way of breaking out of that while loop without a rescue?
I know that I can just say e.each (or just not use the enumerator at all), but for my specific problem I want to do something special for the first few iterations and then something general for the last few.

I want a way of looking at the next value and getting `nil` instead of an error.

Any tips?  There's probably something obvious that I'm missing...

NB. I don't have to use enumerators, but it seems like the easiest way to solve my problem.  So if you have a non enumerator solution (for iterating through an enumerable), feel free to share.  (on that note, maybe I should just use each or each_with_index and use the counter for the special cases...)

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what your *actual* problem is. You may be able to use `each_cons(2)` but there's too little detail to say for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rescuing from `StopIteration` is *the* way to do it. And the only way.*

When you realize that *any* value (e.g. `nil`, as you suggest) returned by `next` could be the next value of the enumerable, it becomes clear that it's not possible for it to return a special-case value, since that could then never be in the enumerable. This is why `next` must raise `StopIteration` when complete instead of doing something more "graceful".

<sub>**Assuming you must use `Enumerator`, as there's probably a better way to solve your real problem without doing so.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  From a performance perspective, does that mean this [the way suggested above] is an undesirable way to iterate through something?  For instance, is tadman's solution considerably more efficient?

Comment: @wrhall They're probably not very different, but you can always run a benchmark yourself to see.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using `each_with_index` like you suggest to have special behavior for the first N? This pattern shows up all the time:

```
a.each_with_index do |e, i|
  if (i <= n)
    # Do special stuff
  end
  # Do regular stuff
end
```

There's a lot of tools in the [Enumerable](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable) toolbox you can make use of.

Comment: Yes, this is very much the behavior that I want to use.  Since (in my head, at least) my question was about StopIteration, I'm giving the answer to the above poster, but thanks for your post.